# How to check if $f(X) \in F(g_1(X), \ldots, g_m(X))$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, extension-field, function-fields, multivariate-polynomial

Let $X=(X_1,\ldots, X_n)$ and $g_1(X), \ldots, g_m(X) \in F(X)$ for a field $F$.
Which algorithms or methods are used to determine if $f(X) \in F(g_1(X), \ldots, g_m(X))$ is true for a given $f(X) \in F(X)$?